# Powershell/github issue with adding SSH key to clipboard

Tags: powershell, github

I am trying to add my SSH key to Github ,however I came across an issue:

I have tried running the following command in Windows Powershell to get the key:

```
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

But I get the following error:

```
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
```

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip` should work.

More generally, if you wish to run something with the old Command Prompt syntax, you can always wrap it up in `cmd /c` like this: `cmd /c "clip < ~/.ssh/ida_rsa.pub"`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,worked nicely.Now I am trying to clone a git project onto my machine but I get the following error:Cloning into 'storm-starter'...
error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://github.com/nat
hanmarz/storm-starter.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: @Tohmas: Sounds like a completely separate question to me.  Belongs in a separate post.

Comment: Yea,just wanted to ask if he might have any idea about it.Anyway ill make it a separate question

Comment: I don't have any idea about it anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [PowerShell Community Extensions(PSCX)](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) module, you can also use:

```
Get-Content ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | Write-Clipboard
```

Answer (score -1):

Just open the file in `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` with a text editor and copy it with `ctrl + c`.

The `.ssh` folder will probably be in `C:\Users\YourUser\.ssh`.